# Managing unsigned long long via hashtable

Tags: c, hashtable, unsigned-long-long-int

I'm looking for a solution on how to manage (accumulate, search, sort) hundreds of thousands of unsigned long long. Basically, I need to collect a number of hits for each hash represented as unsigned long long, then sort the list and get the top 100. But it should be fast and memory-efficient.

I'm writing in ansi c for Linux. Is there any library that could help to implement that?

Thanks!

Comment: Your requirements have nothing to do with a hash table, and in fact a hash table does not allow efficiently implementing them.

Comment: What would you recommend?